# check if data is already loaded in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, pivot

I am coding for a basic windows phone app. First time when the application is getting launched, data is getting loaded properly in listbox. Now after clicking on any item in list box, I am navigating to another page. But when I press back button to come back to main page. a new set of similar data is getting appended to list box items. how do I check whether data was already loaded or not.

`InitializeComponent();`

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
```

In my call back MainPage_Loaded I am binding my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see how navigation works in Windows Phone. When you go back, the Loaded event gets raised every tmie.

The constructor, however, gets called only when the page is created the first time. When you go back, you actually don't call the constructor again, the page is cached. So, in order to stop the data from loading again, you might want to try loading it in the constructor. That's the simplest way.

The other way includes some form of a bool flag which keeps track of that.

Comment: Or in the `OnNavigatedTo` event and populating if `e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New`.

Comment: Thanks...I am going to try both of them now

Comment: @igrali: Hi,I am using User Control in windows phone application.But i need to call (Flag) Pageload=0 at every time 
when navigate to this page again. first time only called constructor But second time constructor 
won't call.Used navigationTo method but this is not applicable for User Control page.
Any other Soution for this(like page load in Asp .net) ?  
`code`
public WindowsPhoneControl1()   //Constructor
{
   InitializeComponent();
   bool PageLoad = 0; 
}